# Dreamweaver - template not recognising child files until they are opened

Tags: dreamweaver

I've got a new section for a website which I have generated for a data source and it has markup for using a Dreamweaver template.

When I add the new files and folders to the site , then update my template , it doesn't find the new files to update.

If I open one of the new files , make a change in the template , then it recognises the new file is using the template. So it's almost like I have to touch all the files with Dreamweaver first.

I've tried to open all the new files which need to use the template but then Dreamweaver CS4 crashes, I presume because of the number of files it's opening.

Anyway, does anyone know if there is a way to make Dreamweaver recognise that a block of new files belong to the template , it doesn't seem to just work automatically

Thanks
Chris

Answer (score 3):

You can force Dreamweaver to recreate it's site cache, which should cause it to recognize the newly added files. You can do this by going to:
Site -> Advanced -> Recreate Site Cache

Or on the Files panel, click the Options menu on the upper right of the panel, select Site -> Recreate Site Cache.

If Recreate Site Cache is disabled in the Site menu or on the Files panel options menu, then the site cache has been disabled in the site definition. Go to: Site -> Manage Sites..., select your site, and click Edit. IN Dreamweaver CS4 on the Local Info category, there is a Enable Cache checkbox, check it and click OK. IN Dreamweaver CS5, you'll need to expand the Advanced Settings, and then select Local Info, and check the Enable Cache checkbox.